Limiting or Restricting [\S\s] in regular expressions
I'm using Notepad++ and I want to use regular expressions.
My text is really long, and this is just a piece of it.
</>
<p id="eex">be still on </p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>هنوز ادامه داشتن</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>هنوز ادامه داشتن</p>
<p id="eex">What's on tonight?</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>(تلویزیون، سینما) امشب چی نشان می‌دهند؟</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>(رادیو) امشب چی پخش می‌کنند؟</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>(رادیو) امشب چی پخش می‌کنند؟</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>(رادیو) امشب چی پخش می‌کنند؟</p>
<p id="eex">go on</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>[کارگر، کارمند و غیره] کارِ... شروع شدن، سرِ کار بودن</p>
</>
<p id="eex">go on</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>پشتِ سرِ هم یکریز، یک‌بند، لاینقطع، بی‌وقفه، هی</p>
</>
....


I want to match everything from <p id="eex"> to <p id="eex"> (which is repeated many times in my text)  but im not wanting to go beyond the </>.
For example I want to match :
<p id="eex">What's on tonight?</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>(تلویزیون، سینما) امشب چی نشان می‌دهند؟</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>(رادیو) امشب چی پخش می‌کنند؟</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>(رادیو) امشب چی پخش می‌کنند؟</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>(رادیو) امشب چی پخش می‌کنند؟</p>

but I don't want match :
<p id="eex">go on</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>[کارگر، کارمند و غیره] کارِ... شروع شدن، سرِ کار بودن</p>
</>
<p id="eex">go on</p>
<p align=right dir=rtl>پشتِ سرِ هم یکریز، یک‌بند، لاینقطع، بی‌وقفه، هی</p>
</>

In other world I just want my match between </> and </>
Here is what I tried: <p id="eex">[\S\s]+?(?=<p id="eex">.*)
but it goes beyond </>
I did this regex <p id="eex">[\S\s]+?(?=<p id="eex">.*) but it goes beyond </>

How many matches do you expect from your sample inside the first </>...</> section? Maybe something like this regex101 demo.

Don't use notepad++ nor a regex, use a HTML parser.

You need (?s)<p id="eex">(?:(?!</>).)*?<p id="eex">

use : </>\K[\s\S]*?(?=</>)

</>\K: The \K escape sequence tells the regex engine to "forget" everything matched so far, which effectively resets the start of the match right after the </> tag.
[\s\S]*?: This matches any character (including newlines) in a non-greedy manner.
(?=</>): This is a positive lookahead to ensure the match stops right before the next </> tag.

i used your regex as base <p id="eex">[\S\s]+?(?=<p id="eex">.*) :)
image link:
https://prnt.sc/csjF2Q05JxkF

But it also goes beyond </> It just scape </> and it doesn't stop befor it

what did you select in find on notepad++, regex match or just find. use regex

How?  Should i do that

there is image link
